# Не работает LINQ запрос, в котором я хочу получить хэшкод объекта с помощью GetHashCode

Tags: c#, linq

Мне необходимо сделать одноразовую ссылку на скачивание файла, не знаю насколько это правильно, но я делаю так:

1. Переопределяю GetHashCode в классе:

```
public class StoredFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(FileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"));
    }
}
```

2. Генерирую ссылку на основе переданного в GET запрос названия файла, выглядит примерно так - `https://localhost:номер_порта/api/Files/DownloadFile/{file.GetHashCode()}`
3. Запрос из 2 пункта обрабатывает метод `GetFileFromDataBase`, в котором мне необходимо найти файл, у которого хэш совпадает с тем, который в ссылке; я это делаю так:

```
var file = dataContext.StoredFiles.Where(f => f.GetHashCode().ToString() == hashCode).FirstOrDefault();

if (file == null) return BadRequest($"The link is invalid");
```

Когда выполнение кода доходит до поиска файла с помощью LINQ (`var file =...`) возникает следующая ошибка:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(s => s.GetHashCode().ToString() == __hashCode_0)' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Ну вот, не могу понять в чем именно состоит ошибка, нельзя в лямбде использовать получение хэшкода или как-то надо переписать LINQ запрос (видимо да, но как)?

Конечно я могу сделать так и всё будет работать:

```
StoredFile file = null;
foreach (var item in dataContext.StoredFiles)
{
    if (hashCode == item.GetHashCode().ToString())
        file = item;
}
if (file == null) return BadRequest($"The link is invalid");
```

Но хотелось бы сделать с помощью LINQ.

Comment: Судя по `"dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"` ссылка годна максимум в течение минуты? Причём если юзеру не повезёт попасть в конец минуты, то в его распоряжении всего несколько секунд?

Comment: `foreach (var item in dataContext.StoredFiles)` - этот код вытягивает все данные из БД на клиента. Если в таблице много строк (миллионы), то это очень накладно. С помощью LINQ того же легко добиться, добавив `AsEnumerable()` между `StoredFiles.Where`.

Comment: Кстати, тут не просто LINQ, а linq to sql. Добавьте, какую именно ORM используете. Точную версию.

Comment: Вот этот код: `f => f.GetHashCode().ToString() == hashCode` - должен транслироваться в SQL и уйти в БД, чтобы выполниться там. Естественно, СУБД не знает, что такое `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, ссылка годна максимум в течение минуты (в принципе идея и состояла в одноразовой ссылке на Н минут), в принципе я понимаю, что если юзер получает ссылку в, условно, 16:30:55, то у него есть всего 5 секунд, чтобы ей воспользоваться. Хоть это не относится к вопросу, интересно было бы узнать, как реализовать это? ну, чтобы ссылка работала всего (и ровно) минуту

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, супер, `AsEnumerable()` помогло, понимаю, что про это было в ошибке, но не понял, куда это надо впихнуть) я правильно понимаю, что мы вот тут `dataContext.StoredFiles.AsEnumerable()` получаем данные из бд в виде объекта интерфейса `IEnumerable`, а потом уже можем вызывать `GetHashCode()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StoredFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public String TemporaryFilename
    {
        get
        {
            Byte[] str = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{Id} {FileName}");
            String result = Convert.ToBase64String(str);

            return result;

        }
    }
}
var file = dataContext.StoredFiles.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(f => f.TemporaryFilename == hashCode);
```

Как указали, решение действительно плохое. Тогда как вариант можно использовать `MemoryCache` как таблицу временных файлов. Там можно будет настроить время хранения файла. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache. `TemporaryFilename` - генерировать на основе `Id` и `FileName` без доп. атрибутов и загонять в кэш.

Comment: Это всё-таки плохое решение. Тут и проблема точного задания минуты не решена, и вся таблица на клиента выкачивается.

Comment: Да, я тоже хотел предложить [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0) как один из вариантов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну, справедливости ради, вопрос был именно про получение данных с помощью linq, а не про время жизни ссылки)